# Amazon RDS (PostgreSQL): Optimize memory usage

Tags: performance, postgresql, amazon-rds, database-tuning

There is something i did not really understand with Amazon RDS (the PostrgreSQL version). Some queries takes a lot of time to show their results. I have set all relevant indexes (as shown with EXPLAIN). So I think it's not due to my schema design.

I do not use a big machine (m3.xlarge) as bigger ones are too much expensive. My database size is about 300GB.

It seems that Postgres does not use all the available memory (only ~5GB, the "Freeable memory" report of the console shows that there are always ~10GB freeable...). I try to tune my "parameter group" as proposed by [tune-your-postgres-rds-instance](http://www.davidmkerr.com/2013/11/tune-your-postgres-rds-instance-via.html), especially set EFFECTIVE_CACHE_SIZE to 70%. But it does not change anything.

I'm probably wrong somewhere... Any idea ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make more memory available to your queries you would tune your [work_mem](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html).
There are implications to doing that since that's memory per backend.

effective_cache_size actually doesn't deal with memory at all. It's an optimizer parameter.

"Freeable memory" is a good thing - it means that the memory is currently used (most likely) by postgres in the operating system cache.

You can increase your [shared_buffers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html) to allow postgres to use more of it's own memory for caching, but there are limits to it's effectiveness that mean you don't usually want to use more than 25% of available memory to this.

Comment: Is there any similar answer for MS SQL server? I want to optimize the memory usage. Currently the memory usage is a bit too high.

Comment: > that's memory per backend 
...
this seems to be not true, as per other answers I've just seen: each backend might use multiples of that (!)
...see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33616/166815 for details